# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__', rows.append([error, str(dct['value']), str(dct['uniques']),

Tags: python-2.7

> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**', 1 #
>     rows.append([error, str(dct['value']), str(dct['uniques']),

Not sure why I am getting the error # TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**', 1 #

```
def errors_to_csv(errors):
    rows = [HEADER]
    for error, dct in errors.items():
            rows.append([error, str(dct['value']), str(dct['uniques']),
                         str(dct['percentage_total']),
                         str(dct['percentage_runs']), str(dct['links'][:10]),
                         str(dct['additional_info'][:11])])
            if error == 'runs':
                continue
    return rows

def capture_data_in_json(product, recipients, runtype, startdate, enddate):
        errors = dd(lambda: {'value': 0, 'uniques': 0, 'percentage_total': None,
                             'percentage_runs': None, 'links': [],
                             'additional_info': []})
        last_runs = get_last_n_runs(product, RESULTS_LIMIT, runtype, RUN_STATUS, startdate, enddate)
        #last_runs += get_last_n_runs(product, RESULTS_LIMIT, 'distributed-test',
                                     #RUN_STATUS, startdate, enddate)
        log.info('Collected {0} runs'.format(len(last_runs)))
        outputs = [get_file_from_uuid('console.log', run['uuid']) for run in last_runs]
        log.info('Outputs collected')
        for output, link in outputs:
            current = dd(lambda: 0)
            lines = output.split('\n')
            for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                line = ''.join([i for i in line if not i.isdigit()])
                if '[ERROR]' in line:
                    errors[line]['value'] += 1
                    errors[line]['links'] += [link]
                    errors[line]['additional_info'] += lines[index - 5: index + 5]
                    if line not in current.keys():
                        current[line] += 1

            for line in current.keys():
                errors[line]['uniques'] += 1

        total_errors = sum([errors[error]['value'] for error in errors.keys()])
        for error in errors.keys():
            errors[error]['percentage_total'] = round(100.0 * errors[error]['value'] / total_errors, 2)
            errors[error]['percentage_runs'] = round(100.0 * errors[error]['uniques'] / len(last_runs), 2)

        log.info('Analyzed {0} runs.'.format(len(outputs)))
        errors['runs'] = len(outputs)
        with open('data_' + product + '.json', 'w+') as out_file:
            json.dump(errors, out_file)
        return errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You use something like: `dct["key"]` to get value from dct, however it seems that "dct" is not a dict according to the error message：" 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**' " , you may need to check the type of dct.
Try:

```
print repr(dct)
```

or:

```
print type(dct)
```

to check the type of dct.
You could use: `dct["key"]` to get a value, only when it is a dict.

And another place that might cause the problem is:

```
str(dct['key'][:end])
```

this would also raise an error if `dct['key']` is not a list, so you may also need to check type of `dct['key']` if dct is a dict.